# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged generically with std::source_location

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm asking for the cppwinrt version of this c# question: [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist)

As far as I can tell you cant define you own parameterized/generic types in idl.

What do people do? Just have a `.idl` `.h` `.cpp` for each instantiation and copy paste like mad?

Could someone explain how static reflection on function signatures enables a generic implementation?

Comment: With [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) we can finally write a generic implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable "we can finally write" sounds like you recommending that I try to do this. Are you? If so could you sketch the process please? It's not clear to me how static reflection on function signatures enables this

Comment: I said *"finally"*, because extracting a string representation of the current function's name was the only missing ingredient in writing a generic `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation that can be used everywhere.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry I'm still not clear whether you are saying that Kenny Kerr can finally write a generic implementation or that I should. Would any idl be involved in this generic implementation? Have you done this?

Comment: Also would you be able to bind to this from Xaml? you would need an idl type I believe

Comment: `source_location` allows C++ developers to implement the same functionality as C#' `[CallerMemberName]` attribute. Chances of this implementation making it into C++/WinRT? Less than zero. XAML has long been picking up metastases of the .NET Cancer, with the Windows App SDK finally turned into a .NET-only shit show. You won't see any investments into a system that's been on death row for years.